# NetworkX reading Cytoscape json bug?

Tags: json, networkx, cytoscape

I am trying to read Cytoscape Json (*cyjs) into NetworkX graph. No luck so far, I tried other formats too. Here is a sample input:

```
{
  "format_version" : "1.0",
  "generated_by" : "cytoscape-3.8.2",
  "target_cytoscapejs_version" : "~2.1",
  "data" : {
    "shared_name" : "Network",
    "name" : "Network",
    "SUID" : 172,
    "__Annotations" : [ ],
    "selected" : true
  },
  "elements" : {
    "nodes" : [ {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "187",
        "shared_name" : "Node 3",
        "name" : "Node 3",
        "SUID" : 187,
        "selected" : false
      },
      "position" : {
        "x" : -387.81580333030377,
        "y" : 6.552640965689666
      },
      "selected" : false
    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "185",
        "shared_name" : "Node 2",
        "name" : "Node 2",
        "SUID" : 185,
        "selected" : false
      },
      "position" : {
        "x" : -236.0,
        "y" : -66.0
      },
      "selected" : false
    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "183",
        "shared_name" : "Node 1",
        "name" : "Node 1",
        "SUID" : 183,
        "selected" : false
      },
      "position" : {
        "x" : -392.0,
        "y" : -89.0
      },
      "selected" : false
    } ],
    "edges" : [ {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "189",
        "source" : "187",
        "target" : "185",
        "shared_name" : "Node 3 (interacts with) Node 2",
        "shared_interaction" : "interacts with",
        "name" : "Node 3 (interacts with) Node 2",
        "interaction" : "interacts with",
        "SUID" : 189,
        "selected" : false
      },
      "selected" : false
    }, {
      "data" : {
        "id" : "191",
        "source" : "183",
        "target" : "185",
        "shared_name" : "Node 1 (interacts with) Node 2",
        "shared_interaction" : "interacts with",
        "name" : "Node 1 (interacts with) Node 2",
        "interaction" : "interacts with",
        "SUID" : 191,
        "selected" : false
      },
      "selected" : false
    } ]
  }
}
```

this is as simple directed graph:

[image: a three node graph]

when I try to read it using Netorkx

```
import json
from networkx.readwrite.json_graph import cytoscape_data, cytoscape_graph
cyjs = json.load(open("Network.cyjs"))
graph = cytoscape_graph(cyjs)
```

I get the following:

```
...
    graph = cytoscape_graph(cyjs)
  File "/$HOMEDIR/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/readwrite/json_graph/cytoscape.py", line 89, in cytoscape_graph
    node = d["data"]["value"]
KeyError: 'value'
```

Does anybody have a working example of successful input into NetworkX from Cytoscape?

Any help or insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own parser using json, extract edge list, build graph from edge list. Something along the lines of (make sure that the names are unique here)

```py
import networkx as nx
import json

def cyjs2graph(cyjs_file_name):

    cyjson = json.load(open(cyjs_file_name))

    name_from_id = {}
    for node in cyjson["elements"]["nodes"]:
        name_from_id[node['data']['id']] = node['data']['name']

    edge_list = []
    for edge in cyjson["elements"]["edges"]:
        src_id = edge['data']['source']
        src_name = name_from_id[src_id]
        tgt_id   = edge['data']['target']
        tgt_name = name_from_id[tgt_id]
        edge_list.append([src_name, tgt_name])
    graph = nx.from_edgelist(edge_list, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
    return graph
```

Comment: If you have implemented that, please share you solution for other facing the same issue. Maybe you find also the differences to the networkx implementation available here: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/readwrite/json_graph/cytoscape.html#cytoscape_graph

Comment: Thanks @Sparky05, yes the code that you are referring to is the one  that does not work for me - I don't have time to investigate. I have edited the answer above with some bare bones code.

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answer. I tested the following code to add the "stringdb_score" as weight and the "display_name" as node names. The following code assumes an undirected graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import json

def cyjs2graph(cyjs_file_name):
    #Read json
    cyjson = json.load(open(cyjs_file_name))
    #Read nodes and make a dictionary of names
    name_from_id,code_from_id = {},{}
    for node in cyjson["elements"]["nodes"]:
        code_from_id[node['data']['id']] = node['data']['name']
        name_from_id[node['data']['id']] = node['data']['display_name']#Name of the nodes are assumed to be in the "display_name" key

    #Create network
    g = nx.Graph()
    #The assumption next is that nodes has just one name, otherwise the following exception rises
    try:
        assert len(set(code_from_id))==len(set(name_from_id))
    except:
        raise Exception('Names are redundant')

    #Add nodes
    for n in set(name_from_id.values()):
        g.add_node(n)

    #Add edges
    for edge in cyjson["elements"]["edges"]:
        src_id = edge['data']['source']
        src_name = name_from_id[src_id]
        tgt_id   = edge['data']['target']
        tgt_name = name_from_id[tgt_id]
        #Add "stringdb_score" as edge weight
        weight = edge['data']["stringdb_score"]
        if weight>0:
            g.add_weighted_edges_from([(src_name,tgt_name,weight)])
        #
    return(g)
```